# JIT provisioning for Person accounts

Tags: apex, single-sign-on, saml, jit-handler

I am looking to enable user provisioning over SAML and was going through documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/06/how-to-provision-salesforce-communities-users.html

I noticed this limitation.

`Limitations`

```
JIT provisioning is currently not supported for Person Accounts. We plan to add support for this account type in the near future.
```

Now, this document was published in 2014, so is this feature available for `Person Accounts`?

Comment: Officially Person Accounts are still not supported. Since Person Accounts are mostly Accounts, it might work in some cases but yeah.

Comment: @identigral, can you please elaborate more on cases it might work and also if it can be achieved using samlJitHandler?

Comment: It _might_ work for some standard fields on an update only but it's far from a completely workable scenario. As you've discovered, you're better off writing your own handler.

Comment: @identigral okay, so to make sure I have not misunderstood you, If I create a custom handler by implementing `Auth.SamlJitHandler`,  I should be able to create/update person accounts and also will be able to populate standard fields on create/update.

Comment: Your handler can do that, yes. It's worth noting that the contract of `Auth.SamlJitHandler` has to do with a create or update of a `User` object. Other, possibly related records with objects such as Account, Contact or PersonAccount may be needed by your particular config/process/etc but the interface doesn't care about that.

Answer (score 4):

The limitation of Person Account with JIT is no more a limitation now. See below screenshot from login & registration page of experience cloud site.
[image]